# smtp.live.com no reply to AUTH LOGIN

Tags: email, ssl, smtp

After having succeeded in connecting to `smtp.gmail.com` and `smtp.mail.yahoo.com` using the AUTH LOGIN mechanism, I'm trying to do the same with smtp.live.com, but to no avail.

The Server is not responding when I send "AUTH LOGIN". Here's what's happening:

```
S:
250-BLU0-SMTP378.phx.gbl Hello [80.149.109.201]
250-TURN
250-SIZE 41943040
250-ETRN
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8bitmime
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250-VRFY
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2
250 OK

C:
AUTH LOGIN
```

But no Response from the server after that.

Note: a STARTTLS command has been issued before attempting to Login. The communication is running under TLS.

Comment: I've tried with swaks and it works. Are you doing it with your own code? If yes, please post your code. And make sure to send CR+LF as line end to server instead of only LF.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm sending "AUTH LOGIN\r\n".

Comment: Maybe you should show enough code here so one could help. Like I said - it works with swaks, so its probably not a problem of the server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich showing the code is not an option. I could get in trouble. Anyway I solved the issue. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason using `SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method())` with smtp.live.com always fails and produces the issue presented in my 1st post.

After replacing the client method with `SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_client_method())`, the issue was resolved.

It is weird, why this happens only with this particular server.

Comment: That's strange. I have no problems with SSLv23. tcpdump would be interesting to see the SSL handshake.